# How can I improve this query for deleting duplicates?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a document management system.  Some documents were imported from another system.  Due to an error, some of them were imported twice.  I need to delete the duplicates.  I have the document id from the previous system, but can't just delete by that as some documents are associated with multiple accounts and are supposed to be in there twice, so I have to check against that as well.  The associated values are in different tables.  I have created the following script to come up with the doc id's to delete but it is incredibly slow (it has been running for four days on a table with less than 2 million records).

```
declare @docidtodelete int
declare @docid int
declare @sourcedocid varchar(12)
declare @taxid decimal(9,0)
declare @account bigint


select @docid = MIN(d.docid) from DOCS d
inner join CONTENTS c on d.DOCID = c.DOCID and c.FOLID=1
while @docid is not null
      begin
            --get the source document id for this document
            select @sourcedocid = val from VTAB0031 where IDXID=31 and DOCID=@docid

            -- see if there is another document with the same source document id
            select @docidtodelete = isnull(MAX(v.docid),0) from VTAB0031 v
            inner join CONTENTS c on v.DOCID = c.DOCID and c.FOLID=1
            where IDXID=31 and VAL = @sourcedocid

            if @docid<@docidtodelete -- we have a possible duplicate so lets check and see if it matches on account
                  begin
                        select @account = val from VTAB0002 where IDXID=2 and DOCID=@docid
                        select @docidtodelete = isnull(max(v.docid),0) from VTAB0002 v
                              where IDXID=2 and VAL = @account and v.DOCID=@docidtodelete
                        if @docid<@docidtodelete -- we still have a possible duplicate so lets check and see if it matches on taxid
                        begin
                              select @taxid = val from VTAB0006 where IDXID=6 and DOCID=@docid
                              select @docidtodelete = isnull(max(v.docid),0) from VTAB0006 v
                                    where IDXID=6 and VAL = @taxid and v.DOCID = @docidtodelete
                              if @docid<@docidtodelete -- we still have a match so delete
                                                                begin
                                    insert into deletedDuplicates values(@docidtodelete ,@docid)
                                                                end
                        end
                  end
            select @docid = MIN(d.docid) from DOCS d
                  inner join CONTENTS c on d.DOCID = c.DOCID and c.FOLID=1
                  where d.DOCID > @docid
      end
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Since that last select will be executed nearly 2 million times, I expect this would be slow! I never thought I would hear myself say this, but, you could probably improve performance by using a cursor!

Comment: What does the dollar sign mean?

Comment: @p.campbell it's a dig at microsoft, and a -1 from me :P

Comment: @JNK, you seriously downvoted the whole question, because of a joking response to a comment?  I actually like Microsoft, but their stuff ain't cheap.

Comment: @JNK: right, I'd forgotten my sarcasm tags. That 'joke' is so old and tired, it's not even funny. I wonder how OP 'decorates' Oracle?

Comment: @p.campbell: I don't, I avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always better to use set operations rather than procedural operations when working with an RDBMS.

Try this instead:

```
select  DocIdToDelete,
        DocIdToKeep
into    deletedDuplicates
from
(
    select  max(DocId) as DocIdToDelete,
            min(DocId) as DocIdToKeep,
            SourceDocId,
            Account,
            TaxId,
            Count(*) as NumberMatches
    from
    (
        select  d.docid as DocId,
                s.val as SourceDocId,
                a.val as Account,
                t.val as TaxId
        from    DOCS d
                inner join CONTENTS c on c.DOCID = d.DOCID
                inner join VTAB0031 s on s.DOCID = d.DOCID
                inner join VTAB0002 a on a.DOCID = d.DOCID
                inner join VTAB0006 t on t.DOCID = d.DOCID
        where   c.FOLID = 1
                and s.IDXID = 31
                and a.IDXID = 2
                and t.IDXID = 6
    ) Summary
    group by    SourceDocId,
                Account,
                TaxId
    having  NumberMatches > 1
) Duplicates
```

**UPDATE**

I made a new query that should get all duplicate records. And this should run more effeciently as well, using the indexes.

```
create table UniqueDocuments
(
    DocId int not null,
    SourceDocId varchar(12) not null,
    Account bigint not null,
    TaxId decimal(9,0) not null
    primary key clustered (SourceDocId, Account, TaxId)
)
go

insert into UniqueDocuments (DocId, SourceDocId, Account, TaxId)
select  min(d.docid) as DocId,
        s.val as SourceDocId,
        a.val as Account,
        t.val as TaxId
from    DOCS d
        inner join CONTENTS c on c.DOCID = d.DOCID
        inner join VTAB0031 s on s.DOCID = d.DOCID
        inner join VTAB0002 a on a.DOCID = d.DOCID
        inner join VTAB0006 t on t.DOCID = d.DOCID
where   c.FOLID = 1
        and s.IDXID = 31
        and a.IDXID = 2
        and t.IDXID = 6
group by s.val,
        a.val,
        t.val

insert into DeletedDocuments (DocIdToDelete, DocIdToKeep)
select  d.DocId as DocIdToDelete,
        ud.DocId as DocIdToKeep
from    DOCS d
        inner join CONTENTS c on c.DOCID = d.DOCID
        inner join VTAB0031 s on s.DOCID = d.DOCID
        inner join VTAB0002 a on a.DOCID = d.DOCID
        inner join VTAB0006 t on t.DOCID = d.DOCID
        inner join UniqueDocuments ud on ud.SourceDocId = s.val
                                         and ud.Account = a.val
                                         and ud.TaxId = t.val
where   c.FOLID = 1
        and s.IDXID = 31
        and a.IDXID = 2
        and t.IDXID = 6
        and d.DocId <> ud.DocId
```

Comment: @Kevin - If there is anything to Karma, then you must have performed some great evil to deserve those table names. I suspect, however, that Satan spewed that table structure from the depths of hell out of pure malice, and the fresh air of self-documenting names will never dilute the stench of this wicked construction.

Comment: While this system isn't exactly something I would design (ok it is nowhere close), it is far from the worst I have to deal with.

Comment: @Jeff, wouldn't run as is.  Had to change this line "having  NumberMatches > 1" to "having count(*) > 1".  This shouldn't affect the query, right?

Comment: @Kevin - That should be fine.

Comment: @Jeff, I did find a small problem with your query.  It will only delete one duplicate instead of all of them

Comment: @Kevin - That was actually by design. From your use of the word "duplicate", it sounded like some of the imports were done exactly twice. Also, since your own query uses the MAX function to locate duplicates, it appears to me to do exactly as mine does. If I get time today, I will modify the query to detect unconstrained multiples.

Comment: @Jeff, don't kill yourself. I can do what I need to get done with what I have now. I was primarily commmenting for the benefit of anyone else who might come along looking for a solution to a similar problem.  Thanks again for the assistance

Comment: @Kevin - Too late, I wrote a new query anyway! Enjoy!